# hours and minutes to seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to convert hours and minutes into seconds which will be send to the API but I am not getting converted seconds. And what value I should send to API.

Html:

```
<form ng-submit="vm.handleAddBrief(vm.briefAttractionData)">
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Duration
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group input-medium margin-top-10" name="duration">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.briefAttractionData.hours">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                   hrs
                                                                 </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.briefAttractionData.minutes">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                  mins
                                                                 </span>
                <!--{{seconds | secondsToDateTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}-->

            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Controller:

```
function addBriefController($scope, $state, $timeout, $location, addBriefService) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.handleAddBrief = function (data) {
            var duration = function(data) {
               var hrs = Math.floor(data.hours * 3600);
               var min = Math.floor( data.minutes * 60);
               var totalSeconds = Math.floor(hrs + min);
            }


        addBriefService.addBrief(data, function (response) {    
            if (response.status === 200) {
                $state.go('newAttraction.image');
            } else {
                $state.go('newAttraction.image');
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: what are you getting in `data` ?

Comment: in data I am getting values from html when clicked on save.

Comment: what does `data.hours` and `data.minutes` contain?

Comment: The calculation you are doing is right, Make sure you get the correct values in data.hours/minutes, and what do you get as the result.

Comment: data.hours and data.minutes is giving me the hours and minutes values in the controller.but no math operation is being performed which is not giving any converted value in duration.

Comment: What `console.log(totalSeconds)` is showing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have the 'duration' function inside the handleAddBrief code. On submitting the form from UI, the handleAddBrief function is getting called and the 'duration' function is being initialized but it is not getting called. Either explicitly call the 'duration' function inside the 'handleAddBrief' function or remove it.
I have created a fiddle for the solution, you can take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/azwspw3x/1/

The code looks something like below:

```
$scope.handleAddBrief = function (data) {
           var hrs = Math.floor(data.hours * 3600);
           var min = Math.floor( data.minutes * 60);
           var totalSeconds = Math.floor(hrs + min);
           $scope.ts = totalSeconds
        }
}
```